# Figuring out which <span> tag was clicked with html5 data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something similar to the following situation:

```
<div id="block">
    <span data-type="a">a</span>
    <span data-type="b">b</span>
    <span data-type="c">c</span>
</div>
```

when clicking on one of the spans, I'd like to return back the data-type.  I tried doing:

```
$('#block').on('click', function(event) {
    var text = $('#block').data('type');
    return text;
});
```

However it's always coming back as undefined.  Any idea as to why this is happening/what the correct solution is? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your div `#block` doesn;t have the `data-type` tag but `span` does. So, handle the click event on span.

```
$('#block span').on('click', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).data('type');
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you had a typo. Not sure if that's why. 1+

Comment: @JoshC - thanks for the edit. copy paste error from the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#block > span').on('click', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).attr('data-type');
    return text;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8c2D/)):

```
$('#block').on('click', 'span', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).data('type');        
    return text;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what it means for it to use event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#block').on('click', 'span', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).attr('data-type');
    console.log(text);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mY5FC/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its checking for the data-type element on the div which isnt there,

you could add a handler for each span to see which one was clicked.

eg

```
$('#block span').on('click', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).data('type');
    alert(text);
});
```